# Enzyme mocked axios PUT not being called

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, axios, enzyme

I have a component which has a form with a submit button which when clicked performs an axios.put which I want to intercept and test.

So far I have the following code simplified for this example:

```
describe('Edit Client functionality', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
      const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
      mock
          .onPut('http://localhost:5000/api/entity/client/1')
          .reply(200, { success: true });
  });

  it('Dummy example test', done => {
      const component = mount(<DummyComponent />);

      const spy = jest.spyOn(axios, 'put');

      component.find('form').simulate('submit')

      setTimeout(() => { 
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
        done(); 
      }, 0);
  })
```

I've tried many variations of the above but can't get the mocked PUT to be called. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: How does your component look like? Is this reference https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html#mocking-modules helpful?

Comment: Can you add the code of  `DummyComponent` to your question?